# Android : Get previous fragment name to do nothing in onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a detected a bug in my app today : When a user clic on an item in my listview, it launch a new fragment with details about this item. But when the user is in this fragment, if he change orientation of the device, the onCreate method of my first class (which fetch my listview) is called, and the app crashed.

I would like to know if it's possible to get the name of the previous fragment, in order to add a test like the following in my onCreate method :

```
if (!fragmentName.equals("common")){
        Log.d("INFO", "Do nothing in this case, because user was in detail fragment before !"),
} else {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        refreshList(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get the name of the previous fragment as its creating a new instance of your Fragment object.

If I am right in what you are trying to do you need to somehow store the object for which you are displaying data so that when the `Fragment` is recreated you can then retrieve the required object. One way is you keep the ID or a unique property of the object in `SharedPreferences` and then reacquire its data when it reloads from a singleton somewhere.

Basically you may need to change the way you retrieve your data or pass it from the original opening `Fragment` so that you can retrieve it again if the second `Fragment` is destroyed.